# Where does the "core" namespace nomenclature derive from?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, nomenclature

I'm relatively new to Clojure but I've noticed many projects implement a "core" namespace; e.g. `foobar.core` seems to be a very common pattern. What's the history behind this and why is it the *de facto* standard?

Comment: Probably just following the `clojure.core` convention. However, Stuart Sierra and others are outspoke about every library (and default Leiningen projects) overusing `whatever.core`.

Comment: Pro tip: `lein new foo.bar` will create `foo/bar` rather than `bar/core`.

Comment: @noahz do you have a link? I'm curious to read Stuart's opinions about this.

Comment: Sorry, it was on twitter, and it might have actually been someone else, not Stuart.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a generic name that represents the "core" functionality of something. The core functions of Clojure itself define a general purpose programming language, with very generic functions you might need in many different problem domains. Functions which are only applicable to a specific problem domain go into domain-specific namespaces, such as `clojure.string` or `clojure.set`.

Tools like Leiningen can't know a priori what sort of a program you're trying to write, so they set you up with a `foo/core` namespace by default, modelled after `clojure.core` -- `clojure.core` is the core functionality of Clojure, so foo.core is the core functionality of foo.

If you can give your core namespace a less generic name, or just use `foo/core` to kick off bootstrapping (such as by holding your `-main` function), that's encouraged, so that the bulk of your code will reside in more semantically meaningful namespaces instead. This helps you find the specific code you want to work on later.